# Android: How to fade in/out titlebar indeterminate progress indicator?

Tags: android, progress-bar, titlebar

In the [K9 mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9) application, the indeterminate progress indicator at the right of the title bar fades out when it's being hidden:

[image]

I've looked through the [source code](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9), and can't see how it's done. As far as I can tell:

- It's not a custom title bar.
- A layout animation isn't being applied to the ProgressBar anywhere in the code.
- It's not being customised by any applied styles.
- It's being configured and shown/hidden with the usual:

  ```
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
  setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
  ```

Any ideas how it's done?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to do. If you want to apply animations, you should get the 'View' object and then apply animation on it. AFAIK, there is no way of getting the `progress bar` from the `Window`. so, You have to create a title bar yourself if you want to apply animations like these.